# I allowed a Facebook user to use my MacBook. Now receiving his alerts

Tags: facebook

I allowed a colleague to log into their Facebook account on my MacBook. I have a Facebook account of my own but it is never used and I don't have the password.

How do I stop the colleague’s alerts popping up on my laptop? Where is my colleague’s Facebook history stored on my system?

Answer (score 3):

Your colleague must not have logged out. Alerts are new, not historic.

Go to facebook.com in your browser to confirm this. In the top (blue) bar, on the far right, look for and click on the down-arrow. In the box that appears, select "Log Out". This should stop the alerts.

Use the "Forgot your password?" link to recover your own Facebook account password.